# Latex Missing $ inserted

Tags: latex

```
\begin{center}

P(k) = P (4) = $\rho\textsubscript{(8, \frac{1}{6})}(4) = \binom{8}{4}{(\frac{1}{6}}^{4}{\frac{5}{6}}^{4}$ = 2,6

\end{center}
```

In this line of my Latex Code it gives me an error:

> Missing $ inserted

I've moved the $ around a lot and it will always give me this error although I previously used similar lines such as this.

Thank you for your help in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not use `\textsubscript` in math mode. As the name says, this macro is for text and not math.

Besides this it seems strange to put inline math inside a center environment. Instead I suggest to use an equation. Please also check your parenthesis, something seems to be missing...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
P(k) = P (4) = \rho_{(8, \frac{1}{6})}(4) = \binom{8}{4}{(\frac{1}{6}}^{4}{\frac{5}{6}}^{4} = 2,6
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: removing the textsubscript did the Job. Thank you.